# Find the branch Target Buffer(BTB) size

Tags: c, performance, hardware, reverse-engineering, branch-prediction

Is there anyway to reverse engineering the organization of the processors branch predictor in order to find the branch Target Buffer(BTB) size with a C program?

If yes, do you have any idea how should the program be?

I can think of a program which runs different number of branches where I can plot the execution time diagram by the number of branches and where I can see a knee in the diagram there is where the number of branches is equal to the number of BTBs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BTB size for Haswell, Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge, and Skylake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512886/btb-size-for-haswell-sandy-bridge-ivy-bridge-and-skylake)

Comment: Check http://xania.org/201602/bpu-part-one Static branch prediction on newer Intel processors
http://xania.org/201602/bpu-part-two Branch prediction - part two and later his publications in same tag; test code is at https://github.com/mattgodbolt/agner (tests/btb*py). It is better not to draw just execution time, but use micro-architecture specific hardware performance counters to get stats in BTB misses. Is your cpu x86, Intel or AMD, or you want ARM or you want universal test?